# Get raw params rather than the "processed into hashes" versions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails 3 question.

If i send a request like this `PUT http://myapp/posts/123?post[title]=hello`

then in my controller i get `params = {:id => 123, :post => {:title => "hello"}}`

This is fine normally and usually useful for eg `Post.create(params[:post])`

However, on this occasion i need to get access to the 'raw' form of the params so i can order them pull out the values, dealing with them all as simple strings, ie i want them listed so the param name is `"post[title]"` and the param value is `"hello"`.

Is there any way i get get these values?  I thought there might be a method of `request` that has the params in their original stringy form but i can't find one.

It had occurred to me to try to convert the hash back into a string with to_param but this seems a but dirty and possibly unecessary.

As a bonus, i'd like it to ignore the :id parameter, literally just taking the part after the ? in the original request.  In fact, if i can just get back the original request string, ie `"http://myapp/posts/123?post[title]=hello"` then that would do: i could split on the ? and take it from there.  It just occurred to me that i can probably get it out of a header.  In the meantime though, if anyone knows a nicer way then tell me please :)

Grateful for any advice - max

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't do the parsing by hand, please. Grab the URI from the [Rails request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html#method-i-url):

```
url = request.url
# Or, depending on the Rails version and stack
url = request.request_uri
# Or even
url = request.scheme + '://' + request.host_with_port + request.fullpath
```

The return value from `request.url` seems to depend on your server stack, `request.request_uri` is supposed to fix that but doesn't seem to exist in Rails 3.1. The third "build it all yourself" approach should produce consistent results everywhere. Sigh.

Then, once you have the URI, use [`URI.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse) and [`URI.decode_www_form`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-decode_www_form) to parse it:

```
u = URI.parse(url)
q = URI.decode_www_form(u.query)
# if u.query was "a=b&c=d&a=x" then q is
# [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["a", "x"]]
```

Comment: I don't know how i missed request.url, i thought i'd tried it and drawn a blank but obviously messed something up as that gives me the full url now, thanks.  However, `URI.decode_www_form(u.query)` is blowing up with `NoMethodError (You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.empty?):`

Comment: Further info:  request.url is actually just returning the path part for me (that's why i discounted it earlier).  So, i guess that is meaning that some variable to hold the params is being set to nil, which is what's blowing up subsequently in your code example.

Comment: @Max: Which version of Ruby and Rails and what is `u.class`? If you're just getting that path from `request.uri` then `URI.parse` won't give you an `URI::HTTP` and so no `query` method.

Comment: ruby="ruby 1.9.2p0", rails = "3.0.7", u.class = URI::HTTP

Comment: @Max: I added an update with a few other variations on `request.url`, gotta' love standardization :)

Comment: thanks @mu.  You're right i think that it's stack dependent.  My app is hosted on heroku and i get different results from curling that to what i get from curling my local webrick server.  This has persuaded me to change my approach so that i no longer need to poke around in the request at all in order to do what i need to do.  So it's a bit irrelevant now except as a lesson in keeping things simple.  :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: undefined method `decode_www_form' for URI:Module with rails 2.x :|

Comment: @rogerdpack: Rails 2 with Ruby 1.8.7? There is no `decode_www_form` in 1.8.7's URI (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) but there is in 1.9.3 (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-decode_www_form). Maybe check the [backports gem](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) or just copy over the necessary stuff by hand.

Answer (score 3):

`Request#body` and `Request#uri` should help you.  You can get the "raw" request data, but not some intermediate form... though it's not that hard to just split at the ampersands and then again at the "=" if you want key-value pairs ;)