# How to access Rails params before all of the values are stringified?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to be able to inspect the `params` hash before all of the values are stringified by Rails. For example if I am using `application/json` Accept/Content-Type, and I receive:

```
{ "id":1, "post":"Hello" }
```

I want to be able to know that `params[:id]` was originally passed as a JSON integer, not a string.

I also want to be able to do this within a controller spec, which uses a limited set of middleware (or none at all?). Is this possible?

Comment: I believe that all values are passed as Strings in the URL and/or form data and are implicitly converted to their respective types by Ruby. So this might not be easily achievable.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to know it was passed as a JSON integer? If you are expecting an integer for a field, then you can cast it using the `to_i` method.

Comment: Can you explain why you need to know the difference between '1' and 1? You can just cast one type to another, and usually ActiveRecord will do this for you

Comment: Yes there is a reason, no I will not explain it because it is the spec of a personal project which has no relevance to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this post has what you are looking for: [How to access the raw unaltered http POST data in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306310/how-to-access-the-raw-unaltered-http-post-data-in-rails?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
request.raw_post
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-raw_post

Comment: This method only works for POST requests. On any other type of request, it returns an empty String.

Comment: Sending a body in a GET request should not be needed and is highly discouraged. Further discussion on this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/2430657.

Either way, `request.body` and `request.body.read` would print out the values as a String.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441701/get-raw-params-rather-than-the-processed-into-hashes-versions?answertab=active#tab-top - it looks like you will have to parse it out of `request.url` for GET request

Comment: Sadly it looks like there is no `raw_put` either :(